# PyQt5 Qtimer don't start

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, threadpool, qtimer

i'm stucked on a Qtimer that don't start, so the number that i need to update on the GUI is never showed.

i don't want to use a while loop inside the code because i need to change some values in real time without any problem.

i really don't understand why it don't start... or better, it start, but don't run the function update_label.

any suggestion?

Thanks a lot for your time!

here is my code:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.resize(1300, 768)
        self.setMinimumSize(1300,768)
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.setWindowTitle(_translate("Bot", "Bot"))
        
        self.number = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.number .setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1100, 10, 300, 20))
        self.number .setObjectName("number")
        
        
        self.show()
        
        
    
        
        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        self.updater = Updater()
        self.threadpool.start(self.updater)
        
        self.updater.update_progress.latest_number.connect(self.update_number)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def update_number(self, val):
        x = str(val)
        self.number.setText("Current block: " + x)  
        
  
    
class Updater(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Updater, self).__init__()
        self.update_progress = WorkerSignal()
        
        print("started")
        
        
    def run(self):
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(2000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_label)
        self.timer.start()
            
        
        
    def update_label(self):
        
        provider = configfile.provider
        number = str(nmbr.latest_numer(provider))
        self.update_progress.latest_number.emit(number)
        print("update label started")
```

Comment: Can you share `WorkerSignal`'s script?

Comment: Depending on how `WorkSignal` is scripted, you might be getting a silent crash if the error happens on the secondary thread.

Comment: of course! thanks for your reply!

class WorkerSignal(QObject):
    latest_number = pyqtSignal(str)

Comment: but i think that is not related to the signal because if i set the update_label method like run method, it works. so the problem is the qtimer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tyring to understand your script, I reached the conclusion that `QRunnable` is automatically released (or stopped) once `Updater.run(self)` reaches its end.

**But this is supposed to happen**, because that's why you should use a `QThreadPool` in the first place. It is supposed to recycle expired threads in the background of the application.

So, as you're running a `QTimer` in the thread, `QThreadPool` thinks that `Updater` thread is dead, while in reality, the timer is still running on the background of a background thread. So it does its job and releases `Updater` from the Thread pool.

What you must do in order to keep both the Timer and `Updater` alive is to manager the `Updater` thread's lifecycle *yourself*.

So instead of using `QThreadPool` and `QRunnable`, you must go one level lower in terms of abstraction, and use the `QThread` and `QObject` themselves in order to control when the thread is going to be stopped.

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QThreadPool, QRunnable, Slot, Signal, QObject, QTimer, QThread

class WorkerSignal(QObject):
    # Changed pyqtSignal to Signal
    latest_number = Signal(str)

class Worker(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self.update_progress = WorkerSignal()

    def update_label(self):
        print("update label started")
        try:
            provider = configfile.provider
            number = str(nmbr.latest_numer(provider))
            self.update_progress.latest_number.emit(number)
        except:
            print("Error, but just for testing...")
            self.update_progress.latest_number.emit("0")

    def main(self):
        print('Init worker')
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(2000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_label)
        self.thread().finished.connect(self.timer.stop)
        self.timer.start()

class Updater(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)

        self.worker = Worker()

        # Move worker to another thread, to execute in parallel
        self.worker.moveToThread(self)

        # Set which method from Worker that should excute on the other thread. 
        # In this case: Worker.main
        self.started.connect(self.worker.main)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        self.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.resize(1300, 768)
        self.setMinimumSize(1300,768)
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.setWindowTitle(_translate("SniperBot", "SniperBot"))
        
        self.number = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.number.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1100, 10, 300, 20))
        self.number.setObjectName("number")

        # I did this to see the label, as it was not attached to any
        # widget's layout on your script.
        widget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        layout.addWidget(self.number)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        self.scene = widget
        
        self.show()
        
        # Create the Updater thread.
        self.updater = Updater()

        # Connect the Worker's signal to self.update_number
        self.updater.worker.update_progress.latest_number.connect(self.update_number)

        # Start the thread
        self.updater.start()

    def closeEvent(self, evt):
        # Before exiting from the application, remember, we control now
        # the Updater Thread's lifecycle. So it's our job to stop the thread
        # and wait for it to finish properly.
        self.updater.quit()
        self.updater.wait()

        # Accept the event. Exit the application.
        evt.accept()

    # Changed pyqtSlot to Slot
    @Slot(str)
    def update_number(self, val):
        x = str(val)
        print("UPDATE NUMBER: ", x)
        self.number.setText("Current block: " + x)  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

What you can do now is follow this pattern and start implementing from here. There are many tutorials that use the `moveToThread` method. Just be careful to not let the thread or any object be recycled by the python's garbage collector, in order to avoid many other problems.

The script is working, however I use *PySide2* instead of *PyQt5*. So some *variable and modules names* may change, so just rename them when you try to run the script on your end.

---

There were a few errors on `Worker.update_label(self)`, which is just a copied script from the old `Updater.update_label(self)`. I don't know what are the variables: `configfile` or `nmbr` as they are not initialized on your post. So I made a `try-except` block to handle the error and make the script work just for testing.

Comment: you were very kind and formidable!

Thanks so much for the explanation and the pattern!